# What are the -i and -o options of wlconf for?

Tags: options

```
 Version = 1.2


# defaults
binary_name="/lib/firmware/ti-connectivity/wl18xx-conf.bin"
wlconf_path="/usr/sbin/wlconf/"
ini_path="/usr/sbin/wlconf/official_inis"

{body of code} basically, the user answers questions like "How many antennas are attached and the answer is stored in a variable


# finally write values to binary
./wlconf -i $binary_name -o $binary_name -s wl18xx.phy.number_of_assembled_ant2_4=$number_2_4G_antenna

./wlconf -i $binary_name -o $binary_name -s wl18xx.phy.number_of_assembled_ant5=$number_5G_antenna
./wlconf -i $binary_name -o $binary_name -s wl18xx.phy.high_band_component_type=$high_band_component_type
./wlconf -i $binary_name -o $binary_name -s wl18xx.ht.mode=$ht_mode
```

My question is simply, what is the function of the "-i" and "-o" commands? The error I keep getting is that "wl18xx.ht.mode" can't be found. I just want to go through and find the exact file it's trying to edit, so that I can better understand what's going on there. I'm very new to linux, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around some things.

Comment: The things you're referring to - `-i` and `-o` - aren't commands. They are options to the `wlconf` command. You need to find / read the man page / documentation for the `wlconf` program to find out what those options mean.

Comment: According to this page: https://github.com/TI-OpenLink/18xx-ti-utils/tree/master/wlconf the `-i` indicates which binary file to use as input. I don't know what the `-o` means.

Answer (score 1):

They are not commands, they are options as a part of the wlconf program. -i gives the location of the input file, -o gives the location of the output file.

Answer (score 0):

The -i appears to me to be broken and, at least, it's help is incorrect since it prints the exact same message as for -o. Use -I (capital I) and -o if you need to create a new configuration binary.